# Error in "import org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_inet.VeinsInetManager" SimuLTE's Highway.ned file

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo, simulte

I tried to install simuLTE and followed the versions according to https://github.com/inet-framework/simulte/releases. After downloading I imported the project in Omnet++(I build the INET3.6.6 before importing simuLTE )
Then I imported veins and tried to import veins into simuLTE according to the instructions given in https://simulte.com/add_veins.html

While running (after building the project) the project lte--> simulation --> card --> omnetpp.ini, I am getting the error in "Highway.ned" file. The screenshot of the errors is attached. I tried different paths in the "import org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_inet.VeinsInetManager" but i am getting error.

//import org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_inet.VeinsInetManager;
import veins.veins_inet.VeinsInetManager;

The error is: cannot resolve module type 'VeinsInetManager'(not in the loaded NED file?)

What is the reason of this error, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if the project is referenced.

Project->Propierties->Project References.

Second if this doesn't works use a import with *.
Like `import org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_inet.*;`

Third check versions. Maybe not compatible.

Comment: " Project->Properties->Project References" had resolved my issue of installation. Thankyou so much!